# How to (re)set password or set single user mode for serial console logon?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Borked network config on ssh key only google compute engine, now i cannot ssh.  Serial console prompts for a password,  update never set one.   What is worse is i do not see how to set parameters to get in via single user mode.

Comment: I believe this is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47252364/3645370. However I can't mark as a dup as the answer didn't get a vote or accept. So I'm going to copy the same answer here.

Comment: Check "Applying a startup script to running instances" in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Comment: Depending on the hypervisor (I've never used GCP), you can get to a grub screen, either automatically or by holding shift och pressing escape when booting. If you can get into the "recovery mode" option, you can get a root prompt without authorization and then run `passwd` to change the password. If this isn't possible, you can also achieve something similar by booting from an external volume with another linux distribution, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have seen, connecting via Serial console requires a username and password to be set up. This must be done in advance, so the serial console will not help you now.

Here are some other things to try:

#### Fix GCE firewall

If the firewall that you changed is just the GCE firewall, you can change it back without accessing the instance. Just [add a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) giving you access on port 22.

#### Restart your instance

If you broke the firewall with an `iptables` command, then the rule probably won't be persisted across a reboot. Try rebooting your instance from the console to see if you get access.

#### Fix a copy of your disk

This is the most complete and powerful repair method, but also the hardest:

1. Snapshot the disk of your instance, creating "orig-snapshot"
2. Create a new disk called "fix-disk" from "orig-snapshot".
3. Create a new instance called "fix-instance" using the debian or redhat images.
4. Attach "fix-disk" to "fix-instance" as a secondary disk
5. SSH to "fix-instance".
6. Inside "fix-instance", mount "fix-disk" on /mnt.
7. You can then access your data on /mnt.  If you just want access to your data, this should be sufficient. If you want to fix the disk, continue...
8. If you know the file you edit that broke the instance, edit it on /mnt and fix it.
9. If you want to set a password for the serial console in the future, run `sudo chroot /mnt passwd`. This will then allow you to set a password.
10. unmount "fix-disk". At this point you can delete "fix-instance", but make sure you don't delete "fix-disk".
11. Create a new instance using "fix-disk" as it's boot disk. This new instance will be a replacement for your original instance, but with the fixes you made in (8) and (9). If you need to keep the same IP address, you will have to move it from your old instance.

Comment: Probably one of the best answers i have ever received.  I was just starting to configure, so will take it out back and shoot it.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot when forgot root password or lock server use google_sudoers

While I assign user to restrict all permission using command
“username” ALL=(ALL:ALL) !/bin/su
“username” ALL=(ALL) !sudo su -

After it effects all the user so other users also cant able  use sudo su -,

> > > /etc/sudoers.d/google_sudoers: syntax error near line 3 <<<
> > > sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/google_sudoers near line 3
> > > sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
> > > sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

So the only option is we have to set startup script otherwise it will block server super user access hence , 1. Go to GCP cloud console 2. Select instance which is affect 3. Edit option 4. Set metadata for instance

- Setting custom metadata is useful for passing in arbitrary values to a single VM or all the VMs in a project. It is also useful for creating startup and shutdown scripts. This documents shows how to complete the following tasks: Set and update custom metadata on a single VM. Set custom metadata on all VMs in a project.

5. key -> startup-script
   Value ->>> #!/bin/bash
   echo root:"your new root pw"| chpasswd

Then reboot server it will reset root passowrd and it will allow users to enter as sudo su – for work as super user.

Answer (score 0):

I also didnt set a password, but luckily the one for root user was the same as the google account for me. So try logging in as root.